# Why my vim split window line so ugly?

Tags: vim, iterm2

When I split window, an ugly split line appears. I wonder why there is grey spaces between the '|' separator. I want only the '|'.

By the way, I use mac iterm2. I wonder some vim plugins cause this, but not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In most fonts, the default *pipe symbol* (`|`) doesn't run the whole height of the display cell. In your screenshot, the spacing between lines is particularly pronounced.

You may either influence this in your terminal emulator settings (by changing fonts or reducing the line spacing), or in Vim by configuring a different character for the vertical separator:

```
set fillchars-=vert:\| | set fillchars+=vert:\
```

This replaces the default with a space (note the trailing space!) You can also try a Unicode character (should your terminal be able to display this); there are some vertical bars that run the whole length.